# export asyncStorage to json file

Tags: android, json, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I used [react-native-storage](https://github.com/sunnylqm/react-native-storage) for save some `key-value` and `key-id` data in `AsyncStorage` in React-Native like below:

```
storage.save({
                key: 'data',     // Note: Do not use underscore("_") in key!
                id: '0',         // Note: Do not use underscore("_") in id!
                rawData: object, // my data object
                expires: null
            });
```

Now I want to add `export` (save) capability to my app and want to now what is the best way to save `AsyncStorage` as a `.json` or `.xml` file to mobile SD card.

I found [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) and [react-native-fs](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs) package for work with file system.

This is how we can read all key based on [react-native-storage](https://github.com/sunnylqm/react-native-storage) package:

```
storage.getAllDataForKey('data').then(items => {
        items.forEach((item, index) => {
             // >>>> item is readable here (Need write this to a json or xml file)
        }
   });
```

Do you know best way to do this task?

How we can do this (write file on SD card) without extra package?